# Laravel development on remote server experiences CSS/JavaScript change delays

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I develop on a remote server. I'm not sure if this is a laravel caching tendancy, but CSS and JavaScript changes tend to be delayed longer than usual. I can make instant HTML and php changes, but sometimes it takes more than a few minutes for CSS and JavaScript changes to be reflected on a page. I do know that .blade.php files are generated and cached within an app/storage/views folder, but even when I delete those the changes are not reflected right away.

I have tried on Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CSS and Javascript are not handled by Laravel.
You can check it from the `.htaccess` of the public folder

Most likely you are hitting the cache browser. One solution to avoid browser cache is to append to the css or javascript a unique identifier whenever there is a new release, e.g.:

```
site/my/css.css?12345
                ^
                |
                + - Change this to force a fresh copy
```

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working best was to clear the cached views on the server, as @dynamic hinted at (Laravel and Blade store these cached files).

AS WELL, to close the tab completely and re-access the webpage fresh. There were cases where it was still cached, and so I would just switch to another browser.